# i have some problem with passing data with queryParams. when i pass string or number it works fine

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router

i'm trying to get object data from one component to another, using queryParams. when i pass string or number it works but when i try to pass object or array i get [Object Object]

this is component i want to get data

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
       
        this.route.queryParams
          .subscribe((params: any) =>{
           console.log(params)
            
          })
      }
    
    }
```

and this is component i want to get it from

```
    constructor(... private route: Router) { }
    
      showFull(song: any) {
        console.log(song)
        this.route.navigate(['song'], { queryParams:{ song } } )
      }
```

and this is its template

```
<div class="songs">
  <div (click)="showFull(song)" *ngFor="let song of filteredSongs let i = index" class="song">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

i'm trying to get object data from one component to another, using queryParams. when i pass string or number it works but when i try to pass object or array i get [Object Object]

Comment: don't do it like this with complex objects. Use State.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spread syntax `...` instead of only the object.

```
constructor(... private route: Router) { }

showFull(song: any) {
  console.log(song)
  this.route.navigate(['song'], { queryParams:{ ...song } } )
}
```

Update on post owner's comment.

Everything is possible

**Solution 1** - use `delete` for any key that you like to discard.

```
delete song.foo;
```

**Solution 2** - use `re-constructor` to support multiple key that you like to discard

```
const {foo: _, ...song} = newSong;
```

Comment: it kind of worked but now i have another problem. in this song object i have another object and now it is [Object Object] :D :D

Comment: I have updated my answer for supporting your issue.